# Making a meteorological output file using specific weather model

Tags: matlab

I want to make a `.mat` output file that consists of meteorological data (latitude, longitude, wind ect).

I have an example output where a "HWM14 / [NRLMSISE 00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NRLMSISE-00)" model type was used.

Does someone know anything about this model type, and whether there are any MATLAB functions which I can use to generate the meteorological outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no in-built MATLAB tool for implementing the NRLMSISE-00 weather model, although you may find this File Exchange submission interesting:

[NRLMSISE-00 Atmosphere Model](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56253-nrlmsise-00-atmosphere-model)

Within that file, there are links to FORTRAN and [C](http://www.brodo.de/english/pub/nrlmsise/index.html) implementations, which the MATLAB code is inspired by. Note I have no experience with the package so cannot endorse it, but it seems like your best option other than writing your own implementation.